# Most efficient way to print an ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, primes

I'm trying to print an ArrayList with upwards of a couple thousand entries (it has to find all the prime numbers between 1 and 1000000). At the end of the program, I call this method:

```
println(myArrayList);
```

While this works with only a couple hundred entries, it takes more time to print the array list than to find the primes once there gets to be more entries.

Would it be more efficient to iterate over it? Or to use a different class?

Comment: OK the problem was that I was using the ACM ConsoleProgram class (the teacher wanted us to learn the library), which prints significantly slower than the standard console. Once I switched to the console, it was much faster, for all of the ways you suggested.

Comment: you should accept your answers or provide comments.

Answer (score 0):

It probably would be more efficient to iterate over it.  `println` will just do a `toString()`, which will produce a lot of `String` and concatenation garbage that you could avoid just by printing directly rather than building up the entire `String` in memory first.

Comment: I tried to iterate over it, and print on each iteration, but then it starts to move in fits and starts, printing in fits and starts. In the end, it takes almost 3x longer than 'println(myArrayList);'. Maybe its just the huge size of the array makes iteration a problem...

Answer (score 0):

I believe StringBuffer is a more efficient and faster way to print stuff. Just build one up in the loop and print it at the end.

Comment: I tried the StringBuffer approach you suggested, but it did not give any significant advantage over 'println(myArrayList);' (I've been timing this program whenever it runs XD)

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing to the console? If you are, console operations are significantly slower than any other output operation (file, socket,etc.). This difference in speed gets evident the more lines you print.

There isn't much you can do to "speed-up" if what you need is to print to the console, but printing to a File will be much faster. Change your program so it prints to a file and you'll notice the speed improvement.

Comment: I'm using the acm ConsoleProgram class. I'm not sure how that would relate to the speed.